# Roll over divs with transition delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a transition delay to my rollover on hover divs, from reading I understand that "`display:none`" can't have a transition delay which is what is stopping me, it needs to be done another way.

I have tried using z-index with no success and also played with visibility but this causes separate issues as I am going to have different text and images displayed as defaut and hovered and the visibility function is affecting spacing as I believe they still occupy the space but don't show.

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/hfs323h7/

Does anyone have or know a way to make it rollover with a transition delay while completely changing the div displayed? Either with pure css, jquery or javascipt?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just use jQuery's built in fade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by CSS with opacity.

```css
.parentItem{ height:200px; background-color:#e7e7e7; float:left; margin-left:1px;width:33%;}


.hoveredItem{opacity:0;transition:opacity 1s;position:absolute;}
.itemDisplay{opacity:1;transition:opacity 1s;position:absolute;}
.parentItem:hover .hoveredItem {opacity:1; }
.parentItem:hover .itemDisplay{opacity:0;}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="parentItem">
<div class="itemDisplay">ok</div>
<div class="hoveredItem">hai</div>
</div>

<div class="parentItem">
<div class="itemDisplay">ok</div>
<div class="hoveredItem">hai</div>
</div>

<div class="parentItem">
<div class="itemDisplay">ok</div>
<div class="hoveredItem">hai</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, is there a way to transition without a fade so it's like a second delay after hover it changes but not faded change?

Comment: If I understood correctly it's like 
`.hoveredItem{opacity:0;transition:opacity 0s 1s ;position:absolute;}
.itemDisplay{opacity:1;transition:opacity 0s 1s;position:absolute;}`
First number is transition time, second number delay

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a fading hovering effect using jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parentItem").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).find('.itemDisplay').hide();
    $(this).find('.hoveredItem').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

This is basically checking if a item is hovered and then fade's in the new item.

Here's a fiddle for your case.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfs323h7/2/)

You can then ofcourse also check for a mouseout event,

```
  $(".parentItem").on("mouseout", function () {
     $(this).find('.hoveredItem').hide();
     $(this).find('.itemDisplay').fadeIn();
  });
```